# Pentaho DI Sqlite.db in job not showing transformation changes

Tags: sqlite, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

1) Pentaho/Spoon DI job unzips files & creates sqlite.db file with all those files converted to tables.( used Shell)
2)Couple of tables are to be added to the Sqlite.db from Mysql db using queries.( used table i/p o/p)
2) is a transformation that runs fine individually.

Although the whole job with transformations runs fine too - no error- only that step2) data from queries are not in the Sqlite.db.

In short, a job to create sqlite.db file is able to add tables from files ( maybe bcz it is done in the job itself & not in tranformation) but the ones from Mysql queries in transformation dont make it to the same Sqlite.db.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Please try to rephrase.

Comment: Sure, need to create Sqlite.db from 2 sources- a) file using files in a folder as tables and b) queries on Mysql tables. Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are able to create sqlite tables from the files, but the data from mysql is not added to sqlite. What does your mysql->sqlite transformation look like?

Comment: You're right! Transformation just has 2 steps - Table input to run query on Mysql & Insert/Update to put data in Sqlite. Thanks !

Comment: Run the job/transformation that creates the sqlite table. Afterwards, run the transformation that transfers data from mysql. What does the Step Metrics table in Execution Results say for the two steps?